# Mathematica cannot simplify this expression to trigonometric function

Tags: simplifying-expressions

We are trying to simplify expression `(-1)^(6/7) (1+(-1)^(2/7))`, which is actually `-2 Cos[π/7]`, using different methods. None of them works.

input:

```
#[(-1)^(6/7) (1+(-1)^(2/7))]&/@{TrigReduce,TrigFactor,TrigExpand,ExpToTrig,ComplexExpand,FullSimplify}
```

output:

```
{(-1)^(6/7) (1 + (-1)^(2/7)), (-1)^(
  6/7) (-I + (-1)^(1/7)) (I + (-1)^(1/7)), -(-1)^(1/7) + (-1)^(
  6/7), (-Cos[π/7] + I Sin[π/7]) (1 + I Cos[(3 π)/14] + 
    Sin[(3 π)/14]), -Cos[π/7] - 
  Cos[(3 π)/14] Sin[π/7] - Cos[π/7] Sin[(3 π)/14] + 
  I (-Cos[π/7] Cos[(3 π)/14] + Sin[π/7] + 
     Sin[π/7] Sin[(3 π)/14]), (-1)^(6/7) (1 + (-1)^(2/7))}
```

On the other hand
input:

```
(-1)^(6/7) (1+(-1)^(2/7))==-2 Cos[π/7]//FullSimplify
```

output:

```
True
```

So Mathematica recognized it as an identity expression when you give it the right answer, but is unable to simplify it by itself.
Is it normal behavior?

Comment: `expr // ExpToTrig // TrigReduce` seems to work

Comment: Also `TrigReduce[ComplexExpand[(-1)^(6/7) (1 + (-1)^(2/7))]]`.

Comment: @Lukas Lang and b.gatessucks: The point is that first of all "FullSimplify" should work, which failed. Why would you try to use every possible combination of  simplifying methods, when it is task of "FullSimplify" to do so. Especially when the expression to simplify was not at all complicated, or cumbersome.

Comment: You wrote "the expression to simplify was not at all complicated".  Maple expresses it in terms of roots of ${{\it Z}}^{6}-{{\it Z}}^{5}+{{\it Z}}^{4}-{{\it Z}}^{3}+{{\it
Z}}^{2}-{\it Z}+1
 $.

Comment: Simplification is theoretically impossible, so your remark that FullSimplify must be able to do this is not correct. FullSimplfy and Simplify are just collections of tricks that might or might not work; the box of tricks in FullSimplify is larger and TimeConstrained has a higher value than the tricks  in Simplify. Many simple examples exist where Simplify and FullSimplify fail.

Comment: The existence of the option `TransformationFunctions` indicates that `FullSimplify` does not "use every possible combination of simplifying methods."  For instance, using `TransformationFunctions -> {ExpToTrig, Automatic}` gets you your desired result, so I infer `ExpToTrig` is not used.  (I'm sure `ComplexExpand` is not used, because it uses transformations that assume variables are real, which is not a safe assumption.)

Comment: @user64494, @Fred Simons and Michael E2: Anyhow, I think in `FullSimplify` there is something that is implemented not quite right. If Mathematica is able to judge that `(-1)^(6/7) (1+(-1)^(2/7))==-2 Cos[π/7]//FullSimplify` is `True` then evidently it has the ability in itself to simplify it. But this ability is for some unknown reason restricted when input is `FullSimplify[(-1)^(6/7) (1+(-1)^(2/7))]`. That was my objection.

Comment: (-1)^(6/7) (1 + (-1)^(2/7)) // ComplexExpand // TrigReduce

Comment: Showing equivalence is substantially easier than finding a simplification.